# DialogFlow Fulfillment throws "No Response defined for device"

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using the dialogflow-fulfillment npm package, included using:

```
"dialogflow-fulfillment": "github:dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs"
```

I have to do this, because Google can't seem to manage to upload the 0.6.2 version to NPM. (Which supposedly fixes this error, but no).

Apparently DialogFlow seems to be unable to realize that it has Reponses already defined in the Console. When I call `agent.setContext()` or `agent.context.set()` without adding a Response via `agent.add()` I  get a fulfillment error:

> No Response defined for device: [SOME DEVICE]

even if I have static Reponses defined. The same is true for `agent.setFollowupEvent()`, but there I can just add an empty Response `agent.add(' ')` because it's not executed anyway. But when I do that with `.setContext()`, the empty Response is relayed to the user instead of the static ones.

The problem with `agent.setFollowupEvent()` seems to be fixed in 0.6.2, but I didn't test extensively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After repeatedly losing my mind, I have resorted to simply adding all the Responses defined in the console again. I did this by looping through the `consoleMessages` and adding them.

```
for (let response of agent.consoleMessages) agent.add(response);
```

This seems to work for all Intents, although some further testing might be required.